# SWIFT - How to use performseguewithidentifier from a tableview in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Thank for read my question.

I am having a problem in my UITableView model, which looks like this:

[image: Image structure of my TableView]

I put a Tableview 2 in one cell of Tableview 1 while in Tableview 2, the data appears normally.

The problem is, when I click on the cell of Tableview 1, Detail View Controller is pushed on normally while on Tableview 2 there is an error like this:

```
has no segue with identifier 'toDetailViewController'
```

How can I push Detail View Controller from Tableview 2 like what I can do with TableView 1? Please help me with this problem. Thank very much.

Comment: Are you using storyboards to design your UI? If yes, you need to create a segue using Xcode's interface designer between cells from Tableview 2 to your destination view controller. Using Xcode's property panels on the right, name this segue `toDetailViewController`.

Comment: No, i'm not using storyboards to design UI. I'm initialization tableview & every control by code.There are other ways ? Thank

Comment: Well, yes, there is. Since iOS 7, storyboards allow easy designing of iOS app UI through Xcode. It takes some time to master, check this tutorial to have an overview of how it works: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1. But of course you can also do everything with pure code. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to set your Tableview 2's `delegate` property to your view controller.

Next, you need to handle the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` function, check that the `tableView` var corresponds to Tableview 2, and then push a new view controller using `pushViewController` (if your view controller is a `UINavigationController`) or `presentViewController` (to present he next view controller modally).